# Sending a structure to a database

Tags: c#, sql, database

I got that now no errors showing up but it also doesn't send anything to the db i think it doesn't sees the ComplexStruct i want to read out all the variables made in the ComplexStruct and send them to the db but even this won't work you got any ideas? and how do i declare the variables?

This is the whole code:

http://pastebin.com/7cMrVL1k

everything in the following has to be send to my database my database table structure is like: a,b,c,d,e,f.....,aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,....,ba,bb,bc etc up to cz

And it should all be done in this part:

http://pastebin.com/2RruRgr8

Thx in advance i hope someone could help me out

---

This is what i got now:

```
    }
    private void Main2()
    {
        {
var structure = new { Datavalues = new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12          ,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 ,19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 ,25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110 } };

var fields = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj", "ak", "al", "am", "an", "ao", "ap", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "av", "aw", "ax", "ay", "az", "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be", "bf", "bg", "bh", "bi", "bj", "bk", "bl", "bm", "bn", "bo", "bp", "bq", "br", "bs", "bt", "bu", "bv", "bw", "bx", "by", "bz", "ca", "cb", "cc", "cd", "ce", "cf", "cg", "ch", "ci", "cj", "ck", "cl", "cm", "cn", "co", "cp", "cq", "cr", "cs", "ct", "cu", "cv", "cw", "cx", "cy", "cz",};

            string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=root; 
        password=flex01;database=gen1";


            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(cs))
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO actualvalues (" + string.Join(", ", fields) + ") VALUES (" + string.Join(", ", fields.Select(r => "@" + r)) + ")";
                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + fields[i], SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = structure.Datavalues[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It gives me the following errors:

Error   1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?):

Error   2   A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Seems like quite a lot to go against. Can you identify and post a much smaller example of the problem you are having? Something a little more specific than "it doesn't send anything to the db" must be happening.

Comment: You using parameters wrong. [Take a look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: @Reniuz Good spot, I hit the WinForms code vomit and decided to stop reading.

Comment: I see you pass `tbComplexStruct_Datavalues`, but it seems it should be like `tbComplexStruct_Datavalues.Text`

Comment: Yeah well but look if you look @ the part with the structure.datavalues ( http://pastebin.com/vwW9DG7R ) i somehow need to declare them as a variable to send them to my database through the sql function is this what you meant adam? @AdamHouldsworth

Comment: @Genius it should be Structure.datavalues[0] till [110] but when i use that it says  it can't find structure in the context

Comment: @user1280458 who says? compiler? in run-time?

Answer (score 0):

Fist your question is not clear and don't post your all code to pastebin, just add some code lines in question where you think the problem is. But I saw that your code where you creating sql command it is not quite right. Your command should look like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO actualvalues (a, b) VALUES (@A, @b)";//add c,d and so on
cmd.Parameters.Add("@A", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
cmd.Parameters["@A"].Value = structure.datavalues[0];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
cmd.Parameters["@b"].Value = structure.datavalues[1];
//... add parameters for c,d and so on
```

And like I already posted in comment look at [SqlCommand.Parameters documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx), there is an example how everything is done.

Comment: i am getting the name structure does not excist in the current context

Comment: But thx for the advice on the parameters i get the problem now ;)

Comment: All tough i still can't seem to get the structure loaded

Answer (score 0):

As @renuiz said, you used Parameters wrong.

This is the way how I see the solution in a piece of code:

```
// your structure, that you have defined before:
var structure = new { Datavalues = new short[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... } };

// put all your fields here. !!must be the same length as structure.Datavalues:
var fields = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", ..., "cz" };

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO actualvalues (" + string.Join(", ", fields) + ") VALUES (" + string.Join(", ", fields.Select(r => "@" + r)) + ")";
for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@" + fields[i], SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = structure.Datavalues[i];
```

Comment: So i need to add this to the part where i make the database connection etc right?

Comment: @user1280458 right. Also there you should have ready-to-use `structure` variable.

Comment: @user1280458 the `structure` must be defined in this scope of code. In the example above I put only demo data

Comment: could you have a look @ my main post? I updated it ;) i am messing arround with just this part for like 2 weeks now so please help me out ;)

Comment: @Touchwise Yes, you messed it up ;) why you put for-loop with `i` that is used in the internal for-loop with the same variable name? About exception with Array - add this line in the beginning of the code: `using System.Linq`

Comment: Okay i fixed the array now now i need to fix the second error about the I stuff

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(cs))
                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO actualvalues (" + string.Join(", ", fields) + ") VALUES (" + string.Join(", ", fields.Select(r => "@" + r)) + ")";
                        for (int i = 1; i < fields.Length; i++)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + fields[i], SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = structure.Datavalues[i];

Comment: Got all errors fixed but now it somehow doesn't send anything to my db? without giving any errors?

Comment: @Touchwise sorry, can't imagine what you are doing on your side. Please update your question with the exact information about your problem (without WinForms thing) - only the code that matters, steps you produce, and what result you get